# Regex to validate URL characters and all available TLDs

Tags: regex, url, tld

I'm new to regex and after few days of practicing/learning I manage to write URL validating regex.

```
/^((?:http|https)):\/\/(?=[a-z\d])((?:(?:(?!_|\.\.|-\.|\.-|\.\/|-\/)[\w-\.])+?)(?:[\.][a-z]{2,}))\/([\w-\.~:\/?#\[\]@!$&\'\(\)*+,;=]*)$/i
```

It works perfectly but problem was that I wanted to check all currently available TLDs because regex above doesn't validates unicode TLDs (`XN--RHQV96G` for example) because it allows only letters for domain. I can make it to validate unicode TLDs, but there is no point because it can't validate if entered TLD is real.

Since stackoverflow allows to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), I will include solution I came up with in my answer and I hope someone will find it usefull, but if you have better solution to solve this problem with TLDs, I will gladly choose your answer as accepted answer.

Rules are following:

Any localhost or IP based URLs shouldn't validate (`http://localhost/ or http://8.8.8.8/` for example)

Any URL with authorization parameters or port in it, shouldn't validate (`http://username@example.com/ or http://username:password@example.com/ or http://example.com:8080/` for example)

Only allowed protocols are `http` and `https`... If someone wants to validate ftp or something else, they can add ftp support easily `(?:http|HTTP|ftp|FTP)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to get list of all currently available TLDs from [IANA](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) and include all of them in regex.

```
/^((?:http|https)):\/\/(?=[a-z\d])((?:(?:(?!_|\.\.|-\.|\.-|\.\/|-\/)[\w-\.])+?)(?:[\.](?:aaa|aarp|abb|abbott|abbvie|abogado|abudhabi|ac|academy|accenture|accountant|accountants|aco|active|actor|ad|adac|ads|adult|ae|aeg|aero|aetna|af|afl|ag|agakhan|agency|ai|aig|airbus|airforce|airtel|akdn|al|alibaba|alipay|allfinanz|ally|alsace|alstom|am|amica|amsterdam|analytics|android|anquan|ao|apartments|app|apple|aq|aquarelle|ar|aramco|archi|army|arpa|arte|as|asia|associates|at|attorney|au|auction|audi|audible|audio|author|auto|autos|avianca|aw|aws|ax|axa|az|azure|ba|baby|baidu|band|bank|bar|barcelona|barclaycard|barclays|barefoot|bargains|bauhaus|bayern|bb|bbc|bbva|bcg|bcn|bd|be|beats|beer|bentley|berlin|best|bet|bf|bg|bh|bharti|bi|bible|bid|bike|bing|bingo|bio|biz|bj|black|blackfriday|blog|bloomberg|blue|bm|bms|bmw|bn|bnl|bnpparibas|bo|boats|boehringer|bom|bond|boo|book|boots|bosch|bostik|bot|boutique|br|bradesco|bridgestone|broadway|broker|brother|brussels|bs|bt|budapest|bugatti|build|builders|business|buy|buzz|bv|bw|by|bz|bzh|ca|cab|cafe|cal|call|cam|camera|camp|cancerresearch|canon|capetown|capital|car|caravan|cards|care|career|careers|cars|cartier|casa|cash|casino|cat|catering|cba|cbn|cc|cd|ceb|center|ceo|cern|cf|cfa|cfd|cg|ch|chanel|channel|chase|chat|cheap|chintai|chloe|christmas|chrome|church|ci|cipriani|circle|cisco|citic|city|cityeats|ck|cl|claims|cleaning|click|clinic|clinique|clothing|cloud|club|clubmed|cm|cn|co|coach|codes|coffee|college|cologne|com|commbank|community|company|compare|computer|comsec|condos|construction|consulting|contact|contractors|cooking|cool|coop|corsica|country|coupon|coupons|courses|cr|credit|creditcard|creditunion|cricket|crown|crs|cruises|csc|cu|cuisinella|cv|cw|cx|cy|cymru|cyou|cz|dabur|dad|dance|date|dating|datsun|day|dclk|dds|de|deal|dealer|deals|degree|delivery|dell|deloitte|delta|democrat|dental|dentist|desi|design|dev|dhl|diamonds|diet|digital|direct|directory|discount|dj|dk|dm|dnp|do|docs|dog|doha|domains|dot|download|drive|dtv|dubai|dunlop|dupont|durban|dvag|dz|earth|eat|ec|edeka|edu|education|ee|eg|email|emerck|energy|engineer|engineering|enterprises|epost|epson|equipment|er|ericsson|erni|es|esq|estate|et|eu|eurovision|eus|events|everbank|exchange|expert|exposed|express|extraspace|fage|fail|fairwinds|faith|family|fan|fans|farm|fashion|fast|feedback|ferrero|fi|film|final|finance|financial|fire|firestone|firmdale|fish|fishing|fit|fitness|fj|fk|flickr|flights|flir|florist|flowers|flsmidth|fly|fm|fo|foo|football|ford|forex|forsale|forum|foundation|fox|fr|fresenius|frl|frogans|frontier|ftr|fund|furniture|futbol|fyi|ga|gal|gallery|gallo|gallup|game|games|garden|gb|gbiz|gd|gdn|ge|gea|gent|genting|gf|gg|ggee|gh|gi|gift|gifts|gives|giving|gl|glass|gle|global|globo|gm|gmail|gmbh|gmo|gmx|gn|gold|goldpoint|golf|goo|goodyear|goog|google|gop|got|gov|gp|gq|gr|grainger|graphics|gratis|green|gripe|group|gs|gt|gu|guardian|gucci|guge|guide|guitars|guru|gw|gy|hamburg|hangout|haus|hdfcbank|health|healthcare|help|helsinki|here|hermes|hiphop|hisamitsu|hitachi|hiv|hk|hkt|hm|hn|hockey|holdings|holiday|homedepot|homes|honda|horse|host|hosting|hoteles|hotmail|house|how|hr|hsbc|ht|htc|hu|hyundai|ibm|icbc|ice|icu|id|ie|ifm|iinet|il|im|imamat|imdb|immo|immobilien|in|industries|infiniti|info|ing|ink|institute|insurance|insure|int|international|investments|io|ipiranga|iq|ir|irish|is|iselect|ismaili|ist|istanbul|it|itau|iwc|jaguar|java|jcb|jcp|je|jetzt|jewelry|jlc|jll|jm|jmp|jnj|jo|jobs|joburg|jot|joy|jp|jpmorgan|jprs|juegos|kaufen|kddi|ke|kerryhotels|kerrylogistics|kerryproperties|kfh|kg|kh|ki|kia|kim|kinder|kindle|kitchen|kiwi|km|kn|koeln|komatsu|kosher|kp|kpmg|kpn|kr|krd|kred|kuokgroup|kw|ky|kyoto|kz|la|lacaixa|lamborghini|lamer|lancaster|land|landrover|lanxess|lasalle|lat|latrobe|law|lawyer|lb|lc|lds|lease|leclerc|legal|lego|lexus|lgbt|li|liaison|lidl|life|lifeinsurance|lifestyle|lighting|like|limited|limo|lincoln|linde|link|lipsy|live|living|lixil|lk|loan|loans|locker|locus|lol|london|lotte|lotto|love|lr|ls|lt|ltd|ltda|lu|lupin|luxe|luxury|lv|ly|ma|madrid|maif|maison|makeup|man|management|mango|market|marketing|markets|marriott|mattel|mba|mc|md|me|med|media|meet|melbourne|meme|memorial|men|menu|meo|metlife|mg|mh|miami|microsoft|mil|mini|mk|ml|mlb|mls|mm|mma|mn|mo|mobi|mobily|moda|moe|moi|mom|monash|money|montblanc|mormon|mortgage|moscow|motorcycles|mov|movie|movistar|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mtn|mtpc|mtr|mu|museum|mutual|mutuelle|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nadex|nagoya|name|natura|navy|nc|ne|nec|net|netbank|netflix|network|neustar|new|news|next|nextdirect|nexus|nf|ng|ngo|nhk|ni|nico|nikon|ninja|nissan|nissay|nl|no|nokia|northwesternmutual|norton|now|nowruz|nowtv|np|nr|nra|nrw|ntt|nu|nyc|nz|obi|office|okinawa|olayan|olayangroup|ollo|om|omega|one|ong|onl|online|ooo|oracle|orange|org|organic|origins|osaka|otsuka|ott|ovh|pa|page|pamperedchef|panerai|paris|pars|partners|parts|party|passagens|pccw|pe|pet|pf|pg|ph|pharmacy|philips|photo|photography|photos|physio|piaget|pics|pictet|pictures|pid|pin|ping|pink|pioneer|pizza|pk|pl|place|play|playstation|plumbing|plus|pm|pn|pohl|poker|porn|post|pr|praxi|press|prime|pro|prod|productions|prof|progressive|promo|properties|property|protection|ps|pt|pub|pw|pwc|py|qa|qpon|quebec|quest|racing|re|read|realestate|realtor|realty|recipes|red|redstone|redumbrella|rehab|reise|reisen|reit|ren|rent|rentals|repair|report|republican|rest|restaurant|review|reviews|rexroth|rich|richardli|ricoh|rio|rip|ro|rocher|rocks|rodeo|room|rs|rsvp|ru|ruhr|run|rw|rwe|ryukyu|sa|saarland|safe|safety|sakura|sale|salon|samsung|sandvik|sandvikcoromant|sanofi|sap|sapo|sarl|sas|save|saxo|sb|sbi|sbs|sc|sca|scb|schaeffler|schmidt|scholarships|school|schule|schwarz|science|scor|scot|sd|se|seat|security|seek|select|sener|services|seven|sew|sex|sexy|sfr|sg|sh|sharp|shaw|shell|shia|shiksha|shoes|shop|shouji|show|shriram|si|silk|sina|singles|site|sj|sk|ski|skin|sky|skype|sl|sm|smile|sn|sncf|so|soccer|social|softbank|software|sohu|solar|solutions|song|sony|soy|space|spiegel|spot|spreadbetting|sr|srl|st|stada|star|starhub|statebank|statefarm|statoil|stc|stcgroup|stockholm|storage|store|stream|studio|study|style|su|sucks|supplies|supply|support|surf|surgery|suzuki|sv|swatch|swiss|sx|sy|sydney|symantec|systems|sz|tab|taipei|talk|taobao|tatamotors|tatar|tattoo|tax|taxi|tc|tci|td|tdk|team|tech|technology|tel|telecity|telefonica|temasek|tennis|teva|tf|tg|th|thd|theater|theatre|tickets|tienda|tiffany|tips|tires|tirol|tj|tk|tl|tm|tmall|tn|to|today|tokyo|tools|top|toray|toshiba|total|tours|town|toyota|toys|tr|trade|trading|training|travel|travelers|travelersinsurance|trust|trv|tt|tube|tui|tunes|tushu|tv|tvs|tw|tz|ua|ubs|ug|uk|unicom|university|uno|uol|ups|us|uy|uz|va|vacations|vana|vc|ve|vegas|ventures|verisign|versicherung|vet|vg|vi|viajes|video|vig|viking|villas|vin|vip|virgin|vision|vista|vistaprint|viva|vlaanderen|vn|vodka|volkswagen|vote|voting|voto|voyage|vu|vuelos|wales|walter|wang|wanggou|warman|watch|watches|weather|weatherchannel|webcam|weber|website|wed|wedding|weibo|weir|wf|whoswho|wien|wiki|williamhill|win|windows|wine|wme|wolterskluwer|work|works|world|ws|wtc|wtf|xbox|xerox|xihuan|xin|xn--11b4c3d|xn--1ck2e1b|xn--1qqw23a|xn--30rr7y|xn--3bst00m|xn--3ds443g|xn--3e0b707e|xn--3pxu8k|xn--42c2d9a|xn--45brj9c|xn--45q11c|xn--4gbrim|xn--55qw42g|xn--55qx5d|xn--5tzm5g|xn--6frz82g|xn--6qq986b3xl|xn--80adxhks|xn--80ao21a|xn--80asehdb|xn--80aswg|xn--8y0a063a|xn--90a3ac|xn--90ais|xn--9dbq2a|xn--9et52u|xn--9krt00a|xn--b4w605ferd|xn--bck1b9a5dre4c|xn--c1avg|xn--c2br7g|xn--cck2b3b|xn--cg4bki|xn--clchc0ea0b2g2a9gcd|xn--czr694b|xn--czrs0t|xn--czru2d|xn--d1acj3b|xn--d1alf|xn--e1a4c|xn--eckvdtc9d|xn--efvy88h|xn--estv75g|xn--fct429k|xn--fhbei|xn--fiq228c5hs|xn--fiq64b|xn--fiqs8s|xn--fiqz9s|xn--fjq720a|xn--flw351e|xn--fpcrj9c3d|xn--fzc2c9e2c|xn--fzys8d69uvgm|xn--g2xx48c|xn--gckr3f0f|xn--gecrj9c|xn--h2brj9c|xn--hxt814e|xn--i1b6b1a6a2e|xn--imr513n|xn--io0a7i|xn--j1aef|xn--j1amh|xn--j6w193g|xn--jlq61u9w7b|xn--jvr189m|xn--kcrx77d1x4a|xn--kprw13d|xn--kpry57d|xn--kpu716f|xn--kput3i|xn--l1acc|xn--lgbbat1ad8j|xn--mgb9awbf|xn--mgba3a3ejt|xn--mgba3a4f16a|xn--mgba7c0bbn0a|xn--mgbaam7a8h|xn--mgbab2bd|xn--mgbayh7gpa|xn--mgbb9fbpob|xn--mgbbh1a71e|xn--mgbc0a9azcg|xn--mgbca7dzdo|xn--mgberp4a5d4ar|xn--mgbpl2fh|xn--mgbt3dhd|xn--mgbtx2b|xn--mgbx4cd0ab|xn--mix891f|xn--mk1bu44c|xn--mxtq1m|xn--ngbc5azd|xn--ngbe9e0a|xn--node|xn--nqv7f|xn--nqv7fs00ema|xn--nyqy26a|xn--o3cw4h|xn--ogbpf8fl|xn--p1acf|xn--p1ai|xn--pbt977c|xn--pgbs0dh|xn--pssy2u|xn--q9jyb4c|xn--qcka1pmc|xn--qxam|xn--rhqv96g|xn--rovu88b|xn--s9brj9c|xn--ses554g|xn--t60b56a|xn--tckwe|xn--unup4y|xn--vermgensberater-ctb|xn--vermgensberatung-pwb|xn--vhquv|xn--vuq861b|xn--w4r85el8fhu5dnra|xn--w4rs40l|xn--wgbh1c|xn--wgbl6a|xn--xhq521b|xn--xkc2al3hye2a|xn--xkc2dl3a5ee0h|xn--y9a3aq|xn--yfro4i67o|xn--ygbi2ammx|xn--zfr164b|xperia|xxx|xyz|yachts|yahoo|yamaxun|yandex|ye|yodobashi|yoga|yokohama|you|youtube|yt|yun|za|zappos|zara|zero|zip|zm|zone|zuerich|zw)))\/([\w-\.~:\/?#\[\]@!$&\'\(\)*+,;=]*)$/i
```

This regex is huge (there is 1,348 TLDs), but it works perfectly and I can't find any wrong URL combination it will validate.

It allows only valid subdomains and it won't validate not allowed domain name combinations like `http://.example.com/ or http://-exa..mple.com/`

If you don't care about valid TLDs and only pattern is enough, you can use regex in original question, it's much smaller, faster and works pretty well.

Any answers and comments are welcome if you find any mistake or you can make this regex shorter or faster.

I will update this answer from time to time to include new TLDs from IANA database if there will be any.

Comment: Do you really think that pain-in-the-butt TLD matching is worth the effort, if the rest of the domain might still be invalid due to being syntacical correct but simply not existing? You might also consider using case-insensitive matching, i don't know any regex engine that doesn't support it.

Comment: @SebastianProske Thanks for case-insensitive matching suggestion. For some reason I was thinking that if I use /i, it would return lower case matches even if original text was uppercase. I will update my answer with \i. I agree about TLD matching, there is no 100% validation of URL using only regex without WHOIS, but maybe someone can find it useful.

Comment: @Seb you are quite right. I can't see the value in this. There's also the issue of keeping your regex up to date with the official list. A better approach would be to do what everyone else does: do a basic pattern match to assert the syntax is correct then actually look up the URL in your DNS if you want to also assert the URL is real.